# Dynamically add custom usercontrol to form based on combobox selection without conditional looping

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, user-controls, dynamic-controls

I'm working on a project that requires users to create an unspecified number of capture fields for their customers. In doing so, I would like to create a generic template, wherein they type the name of their new field, and select a type from a combobox. The values for the combobox ('free text', 'boolean', 'decimal', etc.) can be stored anywhere (i.e. I'm not picky about how they're bound).
The selectedIndexChanged event will handle the addition of the appropriate usercontrol. However, since I don't know how many value-types I will be handling (looks like 7 - 9 for now), I would like to avoid code of the following kind:

```
Private Sub cbxType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If cbxType.SelectedItem = "Free Text" Then
        Dim vText As VTText = New VTText() ' This is the usercontrol for text
        Controls.Add(vText)
    ElseIf cbxType.SelectedItem = "Boolean" Then
        Dim vBool As VTBool = New VTBool() ' etc.
    ...
```

My first thought was to use some sort of list/dictionary of key-value pairs when the form loads

```
Dim kList As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object))
kList.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("Text", New vText())
For each kpair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In kList
    cbx.Items.Add(kPair.Key)
Next
```

with something like this in the change event handler

```
Dim myControl = DirectCast(cbxType.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)).Value
Controls.Add(myControl)
```

However, the selectedvalue attribute is empty, and I get an invalid cast exception. I tried casting to Control, and UserControl, but those, of course, didn't work.
Is this approach, barring my incorrect implementation, sound? Is there a better way to do this? Ideally, I want a line that effectively does something like this:

```
Controls.Add(cbxType.SelectedValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option that is similar to what DotNetHitMan suggested previously...

First, override **ToString()** in your UserControls to set how they are displayed in the ComboBox.  For instance:

```
Public Class VTText

    ' ... other code in your UserControl ...

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "Free Text"
    End Function

    ' ... other code in your UserControl ...

End Class

Public Class VTBool

    ' ... other code in your UserControl ...

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "Boolean"
    End Function

    ' ... other code in your UserControl ...

End Class
```

Next, set **FormattingEnabled** for your ComboBox to False, and add instances of your UserControls directly to the ComboBox in the Load() event of the Form:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = False
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New VTText)
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New VTBool)
    ' ... etc ... (one entry per type of your UserControls)
End Sub
```

Now add a Module so you can create an **Extension Method** for Control, allowing you to create a New Instance based on the passed in type of Control:

```
Public Module Extensions

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function GetNewInstance(ByVal ctl As Control) As Control
        Return Activator.CreateInstance(ctl.GetType)
    End Function

End Module
```

Finally, in the Button click handler, cast the ComboBox.SelectedItem to Control and call the **GetNewInstance()** extension function:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim ctl As Control = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Control).GetNewInstance
        ' ... do other stuff with "ctl" ? ...
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ctl)        
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the first time I've used an Extension Method, keen to look into those. However, in both your and DotNetHitMan's answers, instances of all the usercontrols have to be added to the combobox when the form loads. Is there a way to merely set the text, and set each item/index to reference an uninstantiated instance (a to-be-created instance?). What's the reasoning behind adding a new instance to the combobox, then calling GetNewInstance when casting?

Comment: You have **two** pieces of information you want available from the ComboBox, the "friendly name" and the type of the UserControl associated with it.   As such, you need an instance of something to hold those two pieces of info.  In my example, I'm using ToString() to hold the friendly name,  and the UserControl itself to hold the type.   In the other example, he created a custom class to hold that info.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class that holds your controls along with display text and bind these objects as the data source of your combobox. You are then able to achieve your one liner for adding controls to you collection.

Example (Given I have a form with a combobox (Combobox1) and a Button (Button1) :

```
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       If (Not ComboBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then
          GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ControlType))
       End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       'add some controls to the cbx
       Dim ctrl As New MyControl
       ctrl.DisplayText = "TextBox"
       ctrl.ControlType = GetType(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
       Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(ctrl)
      End Sub
End Class
Public Class MyControl 'The thing that i have also done is add the Display Memeber and Value Member on my Combobox.
    Public DisplayText As String
    Public ControlType As Type
End Class
```

Comment: And what if they wanted more than one instance of a particular type added?...like two TextBoxes (First name, Last Name)?  Your approach above would be adding the **same** TextBox over and over which means it would simply move it's location and you'd never get more than one.  You'd have to **Dynamically** create an instance of that control type and add it when the Button is clicked...

Comment: @Idle_Mind your correct, you can change the 'ControlType' property from a 'Control' to a 'Type' and then create an instance in line. Altered my code to reflect this.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this solution out yet, and am slightly confused about what it's doing. Why do you pass in System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to GetType? In this example, does MyControl inherit TextBox? Or, is MyControl a generic control class, where each of my UserControls can somehow be referenced?

Comment: @MahendranNadesan using the Textbox was just an example as i didn't have your user control. You could just replace 'ctrl.ControlType = GetType(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)' with ctrl.ControlType = GetType(VTText) etc etc so its a generic control class.